# How to multithread opening a network connection in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm working on a multi-threaded Java project and one of my threads is contacting a webpage.  Currently I am doing that as follows:

```
URLConnection urlConn = webPageToContact.openConnection();
InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream());
BufferedReader buff  = new BufferedReader(inStream);
```

My question is, is there a way to do this in a threaded way so that while this thread is waiting for the server to respond, other threads in my project can be doing stuff.  I'm thinking of some sort of 'wait' method.  Thanks!

Comment: Eh? All other threads can already be doing something while this is executing. What's your question?

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a Single Thread Pool Executor:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
   service.submit(new Runnable() {
   @Override public void run() {
      URLConnection urlConn = webPageToContact.openConnection();
      InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream());
      BufferedReader buff  = new BufferedReader(inStream);
      // put data in queue or some other data structure
   }    
});

service.shutdown();
```

Comment: Yes, but the executor has to be started only once per execution of the application and reused for web pages loading (several I suppose)

Comment: are you trying to use this as a request listener for your application?

Comment: Is there a reason that the single thread executor is used in your snippet or is it for illustration purposes?

Comment: Actually using Thread or Executor depends on your requirement. So it was just for illustration purpose. If you had some other logic in your application that could reuse the executor.

Comment: Add close() to sample to clarify the life cycle of buff.

Comment: but closing depends on how the inner logic is implemented. If @Nosrettap is looking for some request listener kind of logic then this whole would be wrapped in while(true){ //reading logic }

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Thread webReader = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        URLConnection urlConn = webPageToContact.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader buff  = new BufferedReader(inStream);
    }
});
webReader.setDaemon(true);
webReader.start();
```

Comment: Will this busy wait while the server is being contacted or will it be asleep and then awaken once a response returns?

Comment: @Nosrettap what difference does this make to you?

Comment: Why not use the executor framework instead?

Comment: @MouseEvent Because busy-waiting versus sleeping have different advantages and disadvantages under different situations.